# getting error in create action on symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Well, i'm working on app using symfony 2,when i'm inserting the fields in Moteur entity, i got this error:

> An exception occurred while executing `INSERT INTO Moteur (lib_moteur, Taille, Puiss_max, Type_carburant, Puiss_admin_nat, Puiss_din, Couple_moteur, Puiss_fiscale, Pos_moteur, Alimentation, suralimentation, voiture_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` with params `["ddddddd", 25, 65, "gazoil", 84, 75, "qqqq", 15, "mmmm", 14, 23, null]`:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'voiture_id' ne peut être vide (null)

here is controller of entity Moteur

```
/**
 * Creates a new Moteur entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Moteur();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('moteur_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

routing.yml

```
gv_gestion_voit:
resource: "@GVGestionVoitBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

moteur.yml:

```
moteur:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:index" }

moteur_show:
path:     /{id}/show
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:show" }

moteur_new:
path:     /new
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:new" }

moteur_create:
path:     /create
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:create" }
requirements: { _method: post }

moteur_edit:
path:     /{id}/edit
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:edit" }

moteur_update:
path:     /{id}/update
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:update" }
requirements: { _method: post|put }


moteur_delete:
path:     /{id}/delete
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:delete" }
requirements: { _method: post|delete }
```

Comment: Post your entity and mapping information aswell. I'm suspecting you're missing the `GeneratedValue` annotation (or it's equivalent in YAML) on your id field.

Comment: Please translate the frenc error message

Comment: trasnlation: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048  column 'voiture_id' cannot be null

Comment: @ccKep i'm using YAML

Answer (score 0):

In your Moteur entity you define

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GV\GestionVoitBundle\Entity\Voiture", cascade={"persist","remove"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $voiture;
```

as not nullable and the error tells that the field is empty. Either you need to provide a Voiture entity to the form (or to the action) or you need to change the field to be nullable.

Comment: i don't want to change the field to be nullable, so that i added these two lines to newAction() in MoteurController.php :                    
                $voiture = new Voiture;
  $voiture_id= $voiture->getId();

Comment: @SaraLqadi You also need to set the field on the Moteur entity: $entity->setVoiture($voiture);

Comment: "No route found for "GET /moteur/create": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)"                                                                                                               Heres is the new error that i got :/

Comment: Where do you define the routes? Post your routing.yml

Comment: you can check the routing.yml and moteur.yml, thaaank you for your help

Comment: moteur_create:
path:     /create
defaults: { _controller: "GVGestionVoitBundle:Moteur:create" }
requirements: { _method: post }

Comment: @SaraLqadi you need to remove the line with requirements to allow other methods than POST.

Comment: i got again that error:                                                                                               SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 column 'voiture_id' cannot be null